# Progress 4GL BUFFER-COPY FAILS

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

```
DO ON ENDKEY UNDO, LEAVE:
    FIND FIRST STUDENT NO-LOCK WHERE ST-ID = "TEST" NO-ERROR.
    IF AVAILABLE STUDENT THEN    
    DO:
       CREATE SCHOOL no-error.
       BUFFER-COPY STUDENT EXCEPT STUDENT.Location
       SCHOOL ASSIGN SCHOOL.Location = "MY LOCATION" NO-ERROR.
       IF ERROR-STATUS:ERROR THEN 
       DO:
           DO i = 1 TO ERROR-STATUS:NUM-MESSAGES:   
              MESSAGE 
                " Error no " ERROR-STATUS:GET-NUMBER(i) 
               " txt: " ERROR-STATUS:GET-MESSAGE(i) VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
               STOP.
          END.
       END.
   END.
```

END.

This query is working fine but some time it was creating Empty Record. buffer-copy through some error that why it create empty record but i am not able verify the error because code was happen in LIVE. please help me how to FIX the problem. what type of error buffer-copy will through. 1000 times working fine 1 time it will FAIL. i know this is data defect but  how to FIX. otherwise what type of errors BUFFER-COPY through.

Comment: Exact error would be of a lot of help, perhaps you can find it in some log? Also: is this exact code? There seems to be some syntax errors like it should probably be `FIND FIRST STUDENT NO-LOCK WHERE ST-ID = "TEST" NO-ERROR.`

Comment: this is not a exact code i just wrote for sample

Comment: To find errors in code the actual code is very helpful...

Comment: i mean logic of the code is same......... can you please tell me what are the error BUFFER-COPY will through. at the same time same code is working fine in lot of time some time it trough error

Comment: Without exact error and exact code it's hard to tell. Could be conflict with UNIQUE indices (trying to create records that basically already exists).

Comment: is there any PDF for ERROR List

Comment: any way thanks for replay Jensd......

Comment: If you have an error number please include it in the post. Then I can check what that error number corresponds to.

Comment: if i have error number i can solve the problem. it will not through the error because BUFFER-COPY having No-ERROR.

Comment: There are tens of thousands of possible errors and there is no PDF list of them.

Comment: NO-ERROR only suppresses certain actions -- like an error message and raising the error condition.  The error still happens and it can still be detected and handled -- which includes the code code Jensd was kind enough to post for you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you really don't know what errors occur - you need to start there.

To track general errors after a NO-ERROR statement you can do something like:

```
IF ERROR-STATUS:ERROR THEN DO:
  DO i = 1 TO ERROR-STATUS:NUM-MESSAGES:
    /* Replace MESSAGE with some kind of logging */
    MESSAGE 
      "Error number " i 
      " error no " ERROR-STATUS:GET-NUMBER(i) 
      " txt: " ERROR-STATUS:GET-MESSAGE(i) VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
  END.
END.
```

Once you have the specific error number(s) you can search the [Progress Knowledge Base](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I would write the code as follow. If you use no-error always handle the error. When assigning/buffer copy check if no error then do a validate to confirm that triggers fire correctly. The error handling code can be put in its own procedure and then just called every time you wish to process error messages. (amended it a bit as I would write it, I do not always trap all errors, but error handling depends on various things, but it is a good way during testing to make sure code is setup correctly. Afterwards can remove error handling where not needed before deploying.)

```
FIND FIRST STUDENT NO-LOCK WHERE ST-ID = "TEST" NO-ERROR.
IF AVAILABLE STUDENT THEN    
DO:
  CREATE SCHOOL.
  BUFFER-COPY STUDENT EXCEPT STUDENT.Location
           TO SCHOOL ASSIGN   SCHOOL.Location = "MY LOCATION" 
  NO-ERROR.
  IF ERROR-STATUS:ERROR THEN 
  DO:
    /* insert error handling - for example as as per @Jensd */
    /* this is in case there is something wrong with buffer copy */
    /* maybe a required field is left empty? */
  END.
  ELSE DO:
      VALIDATE SCHOOL NO-ERROR. /* good idea as it raises any issues with triggers */
      IF ERROR-STATUS:ERROR THEN 
      DO:
        /* insert error handling - for example as as per @Jensd */
      END.
  END.
END.
```

Comment: FIND FIRST STUDENT NO-LOCK WHERE ST-ID = "TEST" NO-ERROR.
IF AVAILABLE STUDENT THEN    
DO :
  CREATE SCHOOL no-error.
  BUFFER-COPY STUDENT EXCEPT STUDENT.Location
      SCHOOL ASSIGN SCHOOL.Location = "MY LOCATION" NO-ERROR.
    IF ERROR-STATUS:ERROR THEN 
    DO:
        MESSAGE 
      " Error no " ERROR-STATUS:GET-NUMBER(i) 
      " txt: " ERROR-STATUS:GET-MESSAGE(i) VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
    END.
END.

Comment: thanks for replay i already made the code like please verify the above code.

Comment: I personally would try to check for whatever conditions that could occur (like "school" already exists, "student" record is incomplete etc) rather than throwing in a bunch of NO-ERRORS and handle those. A small note is that you are missing a mandatory "TO" in `BUFFER-COPY source TO target.`

Comment: added the TO :-) Come from not using a compiler. I believe during testing it is good to add validation and as much error handling as needed. When you have solved all the small issues and are ready for final testing and deployment you decide where it makes sense to do error trapping and reporting. Most comon mistakes with buffer-copy is when the TO table has required fields which are not being initialized. And without a validate statement you will not immediately know if there are any issues with your triggers. Which may not be an issue depending on how far up the chain you are.

Answer (score 0):

I will not make a buffer-copy from one to other table stright, you might have index issues as i think you are having.

Better define a temp-table like the target table.

Then make a buffer copy to the temp-table.

Set the rigth key into the temp-table.

Then make a buffer copy from the temp table with the right key fields to the target table.

Try as follow:

Define temp-table t-school like school.

find first student no-lock and so on.

buffer-copy student to t-school.

Assign t-school.location = "whatever".

buffer-copy t-school to school.

Voila!

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to debug the issue is to use "Recent Messages" under Help in AppBuilder provided you are able to run the code directly from it.